# How to disable Monaco context menu?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am using monaco-editor, and am trying to add a custom handler for Command+Enter. But when I press the command key, the Monaco context menu shows up. Is it possible to disable the context menu, or to rebind it to another key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, you can disable it, just set `contextmenu` to false ;)

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
  value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
  language: "javascript",
  // ---------
  contextmenu: false, // or set another keyCode here
});
```

OR, (thanks to @razor8088)

```
monaco.editor.updateOptions({ contextmenu: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to disable contextMenu.
One which you can define while creating editor. Which is similar to answer given by webdeb. 
But if on runtime you want to enable/disable contextMenu, you can use following function.

```
monaco.editor.updateOptions({
   contextmenu: false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
monaco.editor.updateOptions({ contextmenu: false });
```

The semicolon after the false throws an error.